# Parsing jsonobject when entire json is an array?

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I am using gson-2.5 for this. There is a slight difference in the format of these two jsons, where in the first one;

```
"usethis": [
    {
      "id": 111,
      "text": "some text that i would like",
    },
  {
      "id": 222,
      "text": "someothertextiwouldlike",
    }
]
```

I would have parsed this to get "text" this way, and everything would be ok;

```
JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
        JsonElement root = jp.parse(listcontents);
        JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject();

        JsonArray items = rootobj.get("usethis").getAsJsonArray();
        for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            JsonObject item = items.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
            String thetext = item.get("text").getAsString();
            System.out.println("text: " + thetext  + "\n");
            }
```

The difference is that in the second one, I have nothing to get as the rootobject unlike in the first where I used "usethis";

```
[
  {
      "id": 111,
      "text": "some text that i would like",
    },
  {
      "id": 222,
      "text": "someothertextiwouldlike",
    }
]
```

And setting

```
rootobj.get("usethis").getAsJsonArray();
```

to

```
rootobj.get("").getAsJsonArray();
```

just gives me an error. How would I be able to parse the second json?

Comment: Well, you saw it yourself, the second JSON is not a JSON object. Just parse it as an array instead...

Comment: @fge If I'm understanding correctly, I did that too, just let me add that to the question.

Comment: @fge OK, forget what I  just said! It does work that way. It was something else that I had overlooked. My bad. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JsonElement is just a superclass of JsonArray and JsonObject.

```
JsonArray items = root.getAsJsonArray();
```

should do what you want.